# How to Convert a text data into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How i can convert the below text data into a pandas DataFrame:

```
(-9.83334315,-5.92063135,-7.83228037,5.55314146), (-5.53137301,-8.31010785,-3.28062536,-6.86067081),
(-11.49239039,-1.68053601,-4.14773043,-3.54143976), (-22.25802006,-10.12843806,-2.9688831,-2.70574665), (-20.3418791,-9.4157625,-3.348587,-7.65474665)
```

I want to convert this to Data frame with 4 rows and 5 columns. For example, the first row contains the first element of each parenthesis.

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Please check the answer if that helps, and you can accept as well in order to park it as closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("file.txt") as f:
    file = f.read()

df = pd.DataFrame([{f"name{id}": val.replace("(", "").replace(")", "") for id, val in enumerate(row.split(",")) if val} for row in file.split()])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My saved text file contains the following values: (-6.27309968,-3.61442703,-6.19809471,-0.97911288),(-8.13089122,-5.37642912,-5.40591617,-11.47653022),.... I have tried this code but it does not work. It only create a row with multiple columns.

Comment: @Shayanzargari Try to change like this `df = pd.DataFrame([{f"name{id}": val.replace("(", "").replace(")", "") for id, val in enumerate(row.split(",")) if val} for row in file.split("),")])`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = [re.findall(r'([\-\d.]+)',data) for data in f.readlines()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.astype(float)
```

Output:

```
          0         1          2          3          4
0 -9.833343 -5.531373 -11.492390 -22.258020 -20.341879
1 -5.920631 -8.310108  -1.680536 -10.128438  -9.415762
2 -7.832280 -3.280625  -4.147730  -2.968883  -3.348587
3  5.553141 -6.860671  -3.541440  -2.705747  -7.654747
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is basically in  tuple of tuples forms, hence you can easily use pass a list of tuples instead of a tuple of tuples and get a DataFrame out of it.

### Your Sample Data:

```
text_data = ((-9.83334315,-5.92063135,-7.83228037,5.55314146),(-5.53137301,-8.31010785,-3.28062536,-6.86067081),(-11.49239039,-1.68053601,-4.14773043,-3.54143976),(-22.25802006,-10.12843806,-2.9688831,-2.70574665),(-20.3418791,-9.4157625,-3.348587,-7.65474665))
```

### Result:

As you see it's default takes up to 6 decimal place while you have 7, hence you can use `pd.options.display.float_format` and set it accordingly.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.8f}'.format
```

To get your desired data, you simply use transpose altogether to get the desired result.

```
pd.DataFrame(list(text_data)).T
            0           1            2            3            4
0 -9.83334315 -5.53137301 -11.49239039 -22.25802006 -20.34187910
1 -5.92063135 -8.31010785  -1.68053601 -10.12843806  -9.41576250
2 -7.83228037 -3.28062536  -4.14773043  -2.96888310  -3.34858700
3  5.55314146 -6.86067081  -3.54143976  -2.70574665  -7.65474665
```

OR

Simply, you can use as below as well, where you can create a DataFrame from a list of simple tuples.

```
data = (-9.83334315,-5.92063135,-7.83228037,5.55314146),(-5.53137301,-8.31010785,-3.28062536,-6.86067081),(-11.49239039,-1.68053601,-4.14773043,-3.54143976),(-22.25802006,-10.12843806,-2.9688831,-2.70574665),(-20.3418791,-9.4157625,-3.348587,-7.65474665)
# data = [(-9.83334315,-5.92063135,-7.83228037,5.55314146),(-5.53137301,-8.31010785,-3.28062536,-6.86067081),(-11.49239039,-1.68053601,-4.14773043,-3.54143976),(-22.25802006,-10.12843806,-2.9688831,-2.70574665),(-20.3418791,-9.4157625,-3.348587,-7.65474665)]

pd.DataFrame(data).T
            0           1            2            3            4
0 -9.83334315 -5.53137301 -11.49239039 -22.25802006 -20.34187910
1 -5.92063135 -8.31010785  -1.68053601 -10.12843806  -9.41576250
2 -7.83228037 -3.28062536  -4.14773043  -2.96888310  -3.34858700
3  5.55314146 -6.86067081  -3.54143976  -2.70574665  -7.65474665
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I have a saved text file which contains  (-6.27309968,-3.61442703,-6.19809471,-0.97911288),(-8.13089122,-5.37642912,-5.40591617,-11.47653022),.... So, I should first open it and then convert it into a Dataframe. I still have trouble!

Answer (score 0):

wrap the tuples as a list

```
data=[(-9.83334315,-5.92063135,-7.83228037,5.55314146), 
(-5.53137301,-8.31010785,-3.28062536,-6.86067081),
(-11.49239039,-1.68053601,-4.14773043,-3.54143976), 
(-22.25802006,-10.12843806,-2.9688831,-2.70574665), 
(-20.3418791,-9.4157625,-3.348587,-7.65474665)]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
           A          B         C         D
0  -9.833343  -5.920631 -7.832280  5.553141
1  -5.531373  -8.310108 -3.280625 -6.860671
2 -11.492390  -1.680536 -4.147730 -3.541440
3 -22.258020 -10.128438 -2.968883 -2.705747
4 -20.341879  -9.415762 -3.348587 -7.654747
```